# Colors center of attention

Tags: html, css, colors, rgb

I need to know how to center and make a sentence with 2 colors.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 400px; 
height: 400px; bgcolor: 
rgb(121,200,78); color: 
#,#,#;">
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split up your code a bit. First, to make it center, add the following: `text-align: center;`. This will center your content within the 400px width. To make the text centered on the page, change the width to 100%.

For the color, if you mean a background and text color being different, then just change your `color: #,#,#;` to be a hexidecimal or rgb ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)). To make the background color work, make sure to use the `background-color` or `background` instead of "bgcolor". Your HTML would then look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: rgb(121,200,78); color: #COLOR">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If on the other hand you mean to have the words different colors, then to add a second color, I would recommend using a [span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) with the style you would like. Something like this for the full HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: rgb(121,200,78); color: #COLOR1">
  <p>Hello <span style="color: #COLOR2">World</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd recommend diving into the W3 SChools links that I shared and perhaps checking out some HTML and CSS tutorials, a short video or read will go a long way. Good luck on your learning journey!

Comment: Well I am looking for finding color combinations for website designs that are really extra beautiful ! That will be the center of attention . And I was asking how to find them for my future website.

Comment: this is going to depend a lot about your specific site and the theme you want to use. https://coolors.co is a favorite of mine for colors that look great together. Please mark answer as correct (approve) if it was helpful

Comment: What do you mean by it will depend on my specific site ? How exactly do you focus , aiming , finding 2 , 3 , or 4 colors that are the center of attention to visitors when they view my site ?

Comment: What I mean is you are asking an extremely broad question about the UI and UX of your specific site. The colors that you want are going to depend on what message you are trying to portray to your specific user... The link I provided gives some good color themes to use for a site that might draw attention. If you're looking for something that will draw the user's attention that isn't one of those you can always just use black, white, red, and green. I think your original post doesn't properly portray the real question you have, which is too general